# Procedure not automatically generating number as coded

Tags: vb.net, auto-generate

My code is:

```
Private Function CreateID() As Integer
    'finds the current highest ID
    For Each row As DataRow In MedDT.Rows
        If row.Item("MedicineID") > CreateID Then
            CreateID = row.Item("MedicineID")
        End If
    Next
    'returns a value for eventID that is unused as its higher then the current highest
    Return CreateID
End Function
```

It should automatically generate a number which is one higher than the highest value in the DataTable but for some reason it isn't working
I call the procedure in the Form_Load procedure to fill a text box.

Comment: You can avoid this function altogether by declaring your column auto-generated (IDENTITY on SQL Server). Just my 2 cents

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get this working for now, may look at different ways at a later date. It works fine on another form I have, just not this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are scanning a DataSet for the highest MedicineID number but you forgot to increment that value by 1 before returning, just change your return statement to:

```
Return CreateID + 1
```

You should just mark the ID column as IDENTITY and forget about that trivial thing though

Comment: I have just added your suggested change `Return CreateID + 1` and it still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I haven't taken any heed, I'm grateful. Will try your suggestions at a later date.

Found the problem and it is in the code where I fill my DataTable. I was SELECTing the wrong data from the DataBase.

Comment: The problem might lie in the fact that DataRow.Item[String] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx)returns an Object and the implicit cast could be distorting the data in some way. Not to mention CreateID could be of a non-integer type, also casted implicitly to integer on return. Add the type of CreateID to the example code

Comment: Good to know your problem is solved, may you not find yourself in a situation like this again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what Machinarius has said, Data Table itself has an auto Increment option on a column

```
DataColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
DataColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
DataColumn.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
```

so if you are not loading the data from a database you could also use this option.